# My App Crashes When I press A Button In Android Studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I am creating my first app which is when I press a button I simply move to the next page, but every time I press the button my app crashes (Ignore the username and password texts they don't do anything yet). I am trying to move from login to home page.

activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/gradient"
tools:context=".Login">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_user"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/username"
    android:layout_alignStart="@id/username"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/username"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:background="#11000000"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_pass"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Password"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/login"
    android:layout_width="321dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="207dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:onClick="loginButton"
    android:text="Login" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/register"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="139dp"
    android:text="Register Here"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/attempts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
    android:text="Incorrect Attempts: "
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Login.java

```
package com.example.chorehelpers;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
}

public void onClick (View v){
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.login:
            loginButton(v);
            break;
    }
}

public void loginButton(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent (Login.this, HomePage.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

activity_home_page.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"
    tools:context=".HomePage">
</RelativeLayout>
```

HomePage.java

```
package com.example.chorehelpers;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
}
}
```

Please Help.

Comment: Please add your error stack trace as well

Comment: Have you declared your button? For example : myButton = findViewById(R.id.Button);

Comment: I am not able to find my error stack trace

Comment: Are you running this in an emulator? What does your LogCat say?

Comment: No im running this directly to my phone

Comment: Run it in an emulator so that you can see LogCat. There's a reason you don't package your code and run it on an actual device until you've tested and debugged it.

Answer (score 0):

why are u using this method

```
public void onClick (View v){
switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.login:
        loginButton(v);
        break;
}
```

remove it and rerun the app , Hope it woks

Answer (score 0):

```
**Please try to update Login.java class like this,** 

package com.example.chorehelpers;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button loginButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent x = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomePageActivity.class);
                startActivity(x);
            }
        });
}
```

}